# 16-bit numbers multiplication

Tags: binary, logic, vhdl

In this code, I'm trying to multiplicate 16-bit numbers and get 32-bit output. Code has an error. At line

```
    c<=c+a;
```

compiler gives an error: "cant read port 'c' of mode out. What is my mistake? Thank you.

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity circ is
    port (  a    :in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    b    :in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    c    :out  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)
        );

    end entity;

    architecture data of circ is
    begin
process(a,b)
begin
c<= '0';   
for i in 15 to 0 loop
if (b(i) = '1') then
c<=c+a;
end if;
END LOOP;

end process;
    end data;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly what the compiler told you

> cant read port 'c' of mode out

You can't read an output. You're reading `c` when you write `c <= c + a` because `c` appears on the right hand side of the assignment. You'd have to re-write the code like this:

```
signal s : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

process(a,b)
begin
  s <= (others => '0');   
  for i in 15 to 0 loop
    if (b(i) = '1') then
      s <= s + a; -- Use a local signal that we can read and write
    end if;
  end loop;
  c <= s; -- Assign the output to the local signal.
end process;
```

Comment: With using Max plus II at line
        c <= '0';
compiler gives error:
'type in waveform element must be "std_logic_vector"'

Comment: `c<='0'` should be `c<=(others => '0')` as it is a std_logic_vector and not std_logic

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, it was just cut and paste from the OP's code. I'll fix.

Comment: Also note, this code doesn't work as a multiplier. It's just the original posters code fixed up for compiler errors.

Comment: Although with VHDL2008, out ports *can* now be read... set your compiler for the newer standard.  If it doesn't support it, log a bug!

Comment: This code wouldn't work as the `s <= s + a` and `c <= s` statements will all be executed on the same delta cycle, ie they will all evaluate `s` to the value of `s` on this delta cycle. You must declare `s` as a `variable` in the `process`, not a global `signal`. Note that the assignment statement for variable is: `<target> := <value>`.

Comment: @wap26: Indeed, you're right. I'd normally put that as a continuous assignment outside the process. Brain obviously wasn't working right that day.

Comment: @Paul: ok for the assignment of the output `c`but you can't avoid the variable for the step by step calculation of `s`.